# Arrange multiple ggplots with respect to axis ticks

Tags: r, ggplot2

When arranging multiple ggplots it is easily possible to align them with each according to their plot-boundaries as seen below. However, is it also possible to align with specific plot elements?

In the following plot I would like to have the three plots on the top aligned with the three x-axis ticks (D0.5, D1 and D2) in the plot on the bottom (For which the top-plots will of course also have to become narrower).

```
library(ggplot2)
library(gridExtra)
library(ggpubr)

df2 <- data.frame(supp=rep(c("VC", "OJ"), each=3),
                  dose=rep(c("D0.5", "D1", "D2"),2),
                  len=c(6.8, 15, 33, 4.2, 10, 29.5))

p_bot <- ggplot(data=df2, aes(x=dose, y=len, fill=supp)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity", color="black", position=position_dodge())+
  theme_minimal()

p_top <- p_bot + theme(legend.position = "none")

ggarrange(arrangeGrob(p_top, p_top, p_top, nrow = 1),
          p_bot, nrow = 2
)
```

[image]

It is also possible to ignore the legend when aligning as possible with the patchwork package but it is still not aligned to the ticks:

```
library(patchwork)
(p_top+p_top+p_top)/p_bot
```

[image]

In the end I would like to use this in a more complex setting where I have everything aligned to the x-axis ticks on the bottom (meaning the bars of p_bot and p_mid are aligned as well as the D1 ticks of the top plots with the three x-ticks on the bottom):

```
df1 <- data.frame(supp=rep(c("VC", "OJ"), each=3),
                  dose=rep(c("D0.5", "D1", "D2"),2),
                  len=c(6000.8, 15000, 33000, 4000.2, 10000, 29000.5))


df2 <- data.frame(supp=rep(c("VC", "OJ"), each=3),
                  dose=rep(c("D0.5", "D1", "D2"),2),
                  len=c(6.8, 15, 33, 4.2, 10, 29.5))



p_bot <- ggplot(data=df2, aes(x=dose, y=len, fill=supp)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity", color="black", position=position_dodge())+
  theme_minimal() + theme(legend.position = "none")


p_mid <- ggplot(data=df1, aes(x=dose, y=len, fill=supp)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity", color="black", position=position_dodge())+
  theme_minimal() + theme(legend.position = "none")  +  
  theme(axis.ticks.x = element_blank(),
        axis.text.x = element_blank(),
        axis.title.x = element_blank())


p_top <- p_bot +  
  theme(axis.ticks.y = element_blank(),
        axis.text.y = element_blank(),
        axis.title.y = element_blank())



ggarrange(arrangeGrob(p_top, p_top, p_top, nrow = 1),
          arrangeGrob(p_mid, p_bot, nrow = 2), nrow = 2
)
```

[image]

Comment: Load `patchwork` package and try this `(p_top+p_top+p_top)/p_bot`

Comment: thank you. Tried that already. It improves the result as it ignores the legend when aligning, but still does not align to the ticks. Will update that into the question

Answer (score 0):

I think the most straightforward way to do this is to move the legend of the bottom plot to the bottom, and get rid of the scale expansion on the bottom plot. Then each of the pairs of bars in the bottom plot take up 1/3 of the horizontal space, excluding the space taken up by the y-axis. The `ggarrange` command lines up the axes correctly, at least in this simplified case.

```
ggarrange(arrangeGrob(p_top, p_top, p_top, nrow = 1),
          p_bot + theme(legend.position = 'bottom') + scale_x_discrete(expand = c(0, 0)), nrow = 2
)
```

The result looks like this

[image]

Comment: Thank you. You are right that seems to work for this case. However, for the more complex case I am trying to apply it too it does not work anymore (updated the question); at least in the way I tried to adapt it: 
`ggarrange(arrangeGrob(p_top, p_top, p_top, nrow = 1),
          arrangeGrob(p_mid, p_bot, nrow = 2) + theme(legend.position = 'bottom') + scale_x_discrete(expand = c(0, 0)), nrow = 2
)`